# How would I do the C++ equivalence of dynamic cast in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In C++ there is dynamic cast that checks at runtime if an object implements and interface and returns a `nullptr` instead of the object if it does not.

How can I do the same thing in TypeScript. The way that I can think of is to check the existence and type of each property:

```
interface MyInterface {
    value: string;
    lastUpdated: number;
    deleted: boolean;
}

let obj = JSON.parse(inputdata);

if ('value' in obj && 'lastUpdated' in obj && 'deleted' in obj && typeof obj.value === 'string' && obj.lastUpdated === 'number' && obj.deleted === 'boolean') {
    // do something
} else {
    // null case
}
```

Since TypeScript interfaces are not available at runtime I can't even write helper functions to generalize these checks.

Is there a better to do dynamic casts in TypeScript?

Comment: TypeScript features stop once the source is transpiled to JavaScript. There begins the runtime, hence no info available about interfaces and other stuffs living in the TypeScript world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you get what you are asking for if you implement a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

```
interface MyInterface {
    value: string;
    lastUpdated: number;
    deleted: boolean;
}

function isMyInterface(obj: any): obj is MyInterface {
  // You don't really need the first three, just the last three
  return 'value' in obj &&
         'lastUpdated' in obj &&
         'deleted' in obj &&
         typeof obj.value === 'string' &&
         typeof obj.lastUpdated === 'number' &&
         typeof obj.deleted === 'boolean';
}

let obj = JSON.parse(inputdata);

if (isMyInterface(obj)) {
    // do something, compiler knows obj is a MyInterface in this block
} else {
    // null case
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans for future TypeScript version to make it easier to generate these kinds of type guards? I'm fantasizing about something similar to enums in TypeScript that are translated to more verbose JavaScript code at compile time so that I don't have to write that complicated code.

Comment: No, I'm not aware of plans for a generated version of this. However, it's probably really simple to implement on your own.